# javascript evaluation of ruby object inside haml throw undefine method exception

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I have a javascript that should change an haml element only when ruby object is define
unfortunately the "#{project.builds.last.updated_at}" is been evaluated when the page is rendered ragrdeless to the if condition that is false, and therefore I am getting

> "undefined method `updated_at' for nil:NilClass"

on project.build.last.

```
if ((#{@project.builds.size} && #{@project.builds.size}) > 0){  
  document.getElementById("lastSave").innerHTML = "#{@project.builds.last.updated_at}";
}
```

any idea how I can force the evaluation to be in real time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`try`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#try) method:

```
"#{@project.builds.last.try(:updated_at)}"
```

It will generate empty string if there are no `builds`, but it doesn't matter since this part of JS won't be executed under this condition. Though I would advice refactoring, cause inline JS with Ruby interpolations in HAML isn't very readable and easy to debug.